# Unix. Call a variable inside another variable

Tags: shell, unix

Currently I have a script like this. The intended purpose of this script is to use the function Getlastreport and retreive the name of lastest report in a folder. The folders name are typical a random generated number every night. I want to call the variable Getlastreport and put it inside Maxcashfunc.

Example :

```
Getlast report = 3473843.
```

Use MAXcashfunc grep -r "Max*" /David/reports/$Getlastreport[[the number 3473843 should be here ]]/"Moneyfromyesterday.csv" > Report`

Script:

```
#!bin/bash

Getlastreport()
{
cd /David/reports/ | ls -l -rt | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f10-
}

MAXcashfunc()
{
grep -r "Max*" /David/reports/$Getlastreport/"Moneyfromyesterday.csv" > Report
}

##call maxcash func
MAXcashfunc
```

Comment: Did you really mean to pipe the output of `cd` into `ls`?  `s/|/\&\&/`

Comment: And why bother with `-l` followed by cut to remove everything that `-l` added?  Try the simpler: `cd /David/reports && ls -tr | tail -1`

Comment: Why are you doing a recursive grep on a file?  Recursion is only useful for directories, but if Getlastreport is not doing what you think (eg if it introduces whitespace) then you are potentially doing a recursive grep that you do not want.

Comment: Given both the _text_ of your question and the code sample, I think there is a confusion here between a _variable_ (i.e.: `$SOMETHING`) that _hold_ a value, and a _function_ which is _callable_ (i.e.: `\`cmd arg1 arg2 arg3\``)...

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
MAXcashfunc() {
    grep -r "Max" /David/reports/`Getlastreport`/"Moneyfromyesterday.csv" > Report
}

`Getlastreport` - Call Getlastreport and get its output.
```

Comment: Nope. Not working. It just prints out /David/reports/`Getlastreport`/"Moneyfromyesterday.csv which leds me to a no file. 'Getlastreport' is suppose to print out the last file that was modify and get me a number like 343432

Answer (score 0):

If I follow your question, you could use

```
function Getlastreport() {
  cd /David/reports/ | ls -l -rt | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f10-
}
function MAXcashfunc() {
  grep -r "Max" /David/reports/$(Getlastreport)/"Moneyfromyesterday.csv" > Report
}
```

Comment: This seems to send my script into a waiting for command phase. This was the first way I tried it actually and the way I learn it. Not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: I don't think your cut command is correct. That function doesn't return just filenames here.